# how to check that my phone (redmi note 4g ) was rooted before or not?

Tags: rooting

I want to know that how to check it out..
I have rooted my phone 3 times and unrooted also . my phone is in warranty so I  want to know it

Comment: SHA256 checksum of the system partition before rooting and after unrooting would differ. Enough to conclude that system partition has been tampered with. This is what block based OTA updates do to verify the integrity of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

> **In redemi it doesnt seem to be possible if you have did the 'Full Unroot'**

Additional Info. :

In some devices of motorola and sony bootloader need to be unlockeced from which company can find the device was rooted..and in some Samsung devices there is KNOX counter which changes on rooting..

Answer (score 0):

#### 2 steps to tell if your phone is rooted

- First, download [`Terminal Emulator for Android`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app, if you don’t have one already on your phone.

Launch the app and you should get the well-known terminal interface with a text entry prompt.

- Now, check the character right before your entry prompt.

  - If there’s a pound sign (`#`) then you’re rooted
  - Is there a dollar sign? If so, type in `su` and hit enter.
    Should the dollar sign change into a pound sign (#), then you’re rooted!

> NOTE: During that process, you might see a popup asking you to give
> the terminal app superuser permissions, which you should grant.

Hope it help